# Two timezones are UTC-7 but with different datetime appearance

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, utc

I am working on timezones problems. I have a datetime here `2015-8-24 14:00:00` in UTC format. I need to convert it to timezone (UTC-7:00) Arizona and (UTC-7:00) US Mountain Time (USA & Canada).

I think that after converting it, the times should be the same, but am wrong by below code:

```
var utc = DateTime.Parse("2015-08-24 14:00:00") ;

//(UTC-7:00)Arzona
var _timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");
DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, _timeZone);
var convertedResult =  DateTime.SpecifyKind(result, DateTimeKind.Local);

// shows 2015-08-24 8:00:00 AM 
Console.WriteLine(convertedResult.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));


// (UTC-7:00) US Mountain Time (USA & Canada)
var _timeZoneEx = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
DateTime resultex = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, _timeZoneEx);
var convertedResultex = DateTime.SpecifyKind(resultex, DateTimeKind.Local);

// shows 2015-08-24 7:00:00 AM 
Console.WriteLine(convertedResultex.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

See the result? It's different. Expect the reference. thx.

Comment: If you look at the `SupportsDaylightSavingsTime`, it should become obvious - "Mountain Standard Time" does support it, "US Mountain Standard Time" does **NOT** support it (hence the one hour difference)

Comment: @marc_s got't, thx. pls move your question so that I can give you the acceptance.

Comment: Marc is correct, Arizona doesn't use daylight saving time, which is in effect on the date that you supplied.  But also, you should *NOT* be calling `SpecifyKind` with `DateTimeKind.Local`.  "Local" here means the local time zone of the machine running the code.  If you are trying to convert to the local time zone, you would use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.  Otherwise, you're possibly lying to any consumer of the result, since there's no guarantee that the machine's local time zone is the one matching the ID you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `SupportsDaylightSavingTime` property, it should become obvious - `Mountain Standard Time` does support it, while `US Mountain Standard Time` does **NOT** support it (hence the one hour difference).